# Kofax KTA TotalAgility SDK ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, kofax

I have to create a simple Web API that would call KTA .NET DLL. Since this is a net new project, is it possible to do it using ASP.NET Core (for future-proofing) or this can only be done with .NET Framework?

The provided example is only in .NET Framework:

https://docshield.kofax.com/KTA/en_US/7.7.0-o3xtk9orwd/help/API/latest/sampleapp.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call the DLL as that example shows, then you will need to work with the .NET Framework, because that is what KTA runs on. And this will be the easiest way to go.

If you really want to go with .NET Core, you won't be able to load the API dll, but you could do all of the API calls as web service requests.  The examples in the [Web Service Call using JSON](https://docshield.kofax.com/KTA/en_US/7.7.0-o3xtk9orwd/help/API/latest/webservicecallusingjson.html) topic all show calling from JavaScript, but you should be able to do the same from .NET Core.

Even if you go the .NET Core route for this code calling the KTA APIs, keep in mind that if you later need to write code that executes *within* KTA forms or processes, then that will need to be in a .NET Framework assembly.

Comment: Hi Stephen, thanks for your explanation. A bit disappointed but I guess it's best to stick with the .NET Framework. My only other question then, it should be OK to create your project with .NET Framework 4.8 instead of 4.5 as shown in the example, right?

Comment: Yeah that would be fine: the only consideration is making sure that you will have 4.8 installed wherever your code runs.  For example, KTA 7.7 requires .NET 4.7, so if your code will be running on the same system, just make sure the environment will have 4.8.